# Round() is not giving the desired result

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST (6348.4644 AS decimal (6,2)),1)
```

The result is: `6348.50`

Desired result: `6349.00`

Comment: change the last 1 to a 0

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Why should `6348.4644` round to `6349.00`? Do you want it _rounded_ or do you want the _next highest integer_?

Answer (score 1):

If you want *always* rounding to upper side, then use `ceiling` function

```
SELECT CAST ( ceiling( 6348.4644 ) AS decimal (6,2) )
```